# Before commiting the transaction, what happens to the queries on a tables which are being used in that transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a situation where I need to lock 2 tables, until some operations are done on those 2 tables individually. For that I have chosen "TRANSACTIONS". 
So, between "START TRANSACTION" and "COMMIT".. if anyone tries to insert into those tables, what happens to those queries? will they be maintained in the queue and will be executed after the transaction is completed?
Ideally, whats my requirement is.. they should not get inserted until my transaction has got commited.

Please anyone tell me the scenario.

Thanks in advance!
SuryaPavan

Comment: Consider reading the manual:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a transaction is initiated, it's isolated from the rest of the world. That's the I in [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

During the transaction, if anyone tries to insert anything - the insert will occur but it won't break the transaction you are performing in any way. Same rule applies in the other direction.

If you have the requirement to literally lock the entire table for insert until your transaction succeeds - that smells like a bad design and you should reconsider if what you're doing is really optimal.

Comment: Basically, I want to truncate one table and update another table(which are both inter-related). So, until these 2 operations are made.. I dont want anyone to enter records into these tables. If any request comes, they should be in the queue until my transaction is completed. Thats what my requirement is .. still smelling bad? :)

Comment: Well, it smells even worse now :) why would you ever need to truncate tables in production mode? If you require such functionality - lock the tables before transaction, perform transaction so both (or how many queries there are) queries are executed and then unlock the tables. That will put everyone on hold with whatever operation they wanted to carry out and it'll ensure you truncate everything there is. Just remember that this isn't the best solution and that you need to use InnoDB for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If they got inserted before your transaction was committed (that is, in the middle of your transaction), that would make transactions fairly useless.

I assume you're using mysql (since your question is tagged with that)... why not open two command line sessions to your database and try it to see what happens? That would take far less time than posting your question and waiting for an answer, and you'll likely learn more in the process.